# How do I safely call a method which may occasionally run the CPU to 99%?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ikvm

I am working with a server API which was developed by a third-party supplier. The API came in the form of a .jar file, but since we wanted to use it inside of an ASP.NET MVC application, we converted it to a DLL using IKVM. The solution works well for the most part.

However, one day I received some complaints from our user community that our application was running slowly on one of our servers. So I checked into it and discovered that the w3wp.exe worker process running our IIS application pool was running at 99% CPU usage (usually it's less than 10%). I attached an instance of dotTrace to w3wp.exe and discovered that the "hotspots" could be traced to some Java input stream read methods which are being called by the server API:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
```

Looking further at our own source code, I believe I have discovered the offending line on our side:

```
messageDataBytes = dataConnector.getInputStream().read();
```

This line seems innocent enough. Why would it run up the CPU to 99%? And how can I safely call these methods from our application and prevent any misbehavior in these methods to negatively impacting the entire application?

My initial thought is to call these methods from a separate thread which I can kill if it doesn't finish after a certain length of time. Am I on the right track?

Any thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that line in a loop and it keeps returning 0 or an error value? Or does it consume all the time within 1 single call?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that the single call is consuming the entire time.

Comment: @IanAnderson you don't need to guess, re-run dot trace in Tracing mode instead of Sampling mode and it will give you the exact number of times the function was called. That way if you can tell if it is a single call with a long execution time or many short calls with short execution times.

Comment: My suggested first step would be to confirm one or the other theory. If it is the first one, your loop  fails to handle an (unexpected) return value in a desirable way. If b... hm...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Unfortunately I only saw this issue once so far over the past few years, so it's a rare occurrence. If it crops up again I can do a second run of dotTrace.

Comment: I guess my question is more of a general one: given code from an outside source which may occasionally incur unwanted behaviour, how do I mitigate the potential impacts of that behaviour, should it occur? In other words, is there a "safe" way to call the offending line of code?